# exception Collection is read-only error with ASP4.5 on IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, dotnetnuke

I am running Dotnetnuke7 on a shared hosting environment using ASP.net 4.5 and IIS configured in integrated pipeline mode (as required by DNN7).

When I install it on a Win2008/IIS7 server (ASP4.0) at the hosting provider the application runs fine, but when I install it on a Win2008R2/IIS7.5 server at the hosting provider(ASP4.5) I get an exception Collection is read-only when trying to log-in or submitting anything to the site. (For example use DNN search function). See detailed stacktrace below.

The hosting provider checked the .net 4.5 permissions, and also applies apppool-specific permissions, but no luck yet.

Anybody a clue what IIS7.5 parameter or option can be the cause here?

---

Server Error in '/' Application.

Collection is read-only.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Collection is read-only.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[NotSupportedException: Collection is read-only.]    System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseSet(String name, Object value) +6703734   
System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollection.SetServerVariableManagedOnly(String name, String value) +116    
System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollection.SynchronizeServerVariable(String name, String value) +28    
System.Web.HttpRequest.SynchronizeServerVariable(String name, String value) +112    System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVarChanges(HttpContext ctx) +308    System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.SynchronizeVariables(HttpContext context) +9676858    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +151
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

Comment: Definitely sounds like some sort of a security/permissions issue, the AppPool identity has modify permissions on the DNN folder?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumpling on this - I had this exact issue today.

Resolved by two actions for me:

1. Verify isapi filters in IIS for .net 4.0/4.5 etc are ALLOWED
2. I had installed rewriter-modules (Helicon). Once I removed these ISAPI-filters again - all worked fine.

So check **isapi-filters** is my advice and start without any additional filters except the needed .net filters.